# flutter android emulator Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:56237/5LMSAYhIdSY=/

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

i know there is allot of that kind of issue but i try all the solutions but non of them was help.
i try to run my flutter app which run on ios but on the android emulator its not work, i develope it on VS code and pixel 3 API 28 emulator, the output of the command 'flutter run -v' is:

```
> Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:56237/5LMSAYhIdSY=/
> 
>    throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:14:3)
     RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:569:7)
asynchronous suspension
    FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:723:18)
     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:141:18)
      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:682:45)
      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:711:32)
      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:526:5)
      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:36:15)
     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:298:13)
     RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)
     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:141:18)
     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:682:45)
     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:711:32)
     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:526:5)
     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:36:15)
     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:298:13)
     AndroidDevice.isLocalEmulator (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart)
     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:141:18)
     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:682:45)
     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:711:32)
     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:526:5)
     Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:556:7)
     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1184:13)
     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:979:7)
     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1019:23)
     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)
     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)
     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)
```

flutter doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[!] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2018.1)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[√] VS Code (version 1.29.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)
```

Comment: Have you tried running `flutter run --enable-software-rendering`? I think your emulator doesn't support hardware rendering or a problem with your computer graphic card, so you can change your AVD configuration to `software rendering`.

Answer (score 0):

Run `flutter emulators` to display the list of available devices. If you're still having issues connecting to existing devices, for Android Emulator you can select `Wipe Data` on the list of Virtual Devices to reset the device. After that, try running the emulator again.